# How to trigger initial_place_name event in Workflow Component for state machine

Tags: symfony, symfony-workflows

I created an entity with not null `status` property. Workflow Component is configured to use that property for `marking store`. The `initial_marking` option is set to `draft`.

Entity always has got some status, so that property can't be null. This is why when I want to create new entity I have to provide it's initial state - in this case `draft`.

According to doc

> If you initialize the marking by calling $workflow->getMarking($object);, then the workflow.[workflow_name].entered.[initial_place_name] event will be called with the default context (Workflow::DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONTEXT).

However that event isn't triggered, because entity status property was already set to `draft` during creation.

```php
class Training
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $title,
        private string $status,
    ) {}
}
```

```php
$training = new Training('title', 'draft');
$trainingStatusStateMachine->getMarking($training); // <- here `workflow.entered.draft` event should be triggered
```

1. How can I trigger that initial event in such case?
2. What is the purpose of `initial_marking` option if I have to keep my entity valid upon creation?

**added clarification**

The point is that `workflow.entered.draft` event isn't triggered because `$training` status was set during creation. This is why Workflow Component ignores triggering the event because subject is already in the workflow.

To *fix* the situation I should not set the status (leave it `null`) and allow the Workflow to set initial place name. But I do not want to do it, because I do not want to allow my entity to be invalid.

Another solution is to create "fake" initial status for example `init` and add transition from `init` to `draft`. Such case is fine but then `initial_marking` option make no sense.

Comment: What about keeping it a null but just calling getMarking when creating your entity ? You can just keep the constraint to say that it should not be nullable, so you can't persist it if you did not intialize the status

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37421#issuecomment-652293250

Comment: Thank you for the link. I missed that discussion. 

Regards the problem I do not want to use the `null` solution, because I want my entity to be always valid. "fake" initial status is better for me.

Comment: for me `initial_marking: somename` even causes the error Unrecognized option. Did you mean "initial_markings".  symfony/workflow  v5.4.9